# Replace string to match regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the most efficient way to make string match given regular expression pattern?

```
// Something like this:

let phone = '+12345678901';
const phoneRegexp = /\+\d{1,2}\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\-\d{4}/;
console.log(doTheAwesomeness(phone, phoneRegexp));

// Output: +1 (234) 567-8901
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What would you expect the function to do for invalid input, and what implementations have you tried so far for `doTheAwesomeness()`?

Comment: The doTheAwesomeness function will get the right string as it is going to be evaluated somewhere up above.

Comment: I thought of splitting the string and injecting appropriate symbols based on index and it is, obviously, an option, yet I'd like to find out if there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the digits pattern and replace with back reference:

```
phone.replace(/^(\+\d{1,2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, "$1 ($2) $3-$4")
# '+1 (234) 567-8901'
```

You might want to add the beginning of the string anchor `^` and the end of the string anchor `$` to make sure the string match exactly the pattern you specified if you are trying to format a phone number; And also as @TimBiegeleisen commented, if this doesn't match the pattern, nothing will happen to your string, so you need to manually check if the string match the pattern and handle the exception appropriately.

Comment: Maybe add a check as well to see if the string matches the pattern.

Comment: This is awesome! Readable and works just the way it should. Thank you so much, Phisdom!